# Unit Converter Android

Tags: android, converters, calculator

I need some help.

I am building a Calculator app where you can add up number .

I have that part working but the user is able to change the units of the value and this is where I'm running into trouble.

Does anyone know how to get the number to change when ever the different units is picked? I don't want to use a convert button, I want it to change automatically when the unit is selected.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: you probably are looking for a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [onItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) on your Spinner where you select your Unit. In the `onItemSelected()` Method you calculate the new Value and set it as the value of your TextField where your enter the amount of units. Maybe you need to save the selected Unit type in a temp-variable after every change so you can use the old value on a new change Event.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, add something similar to this:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    // Code for converting your value
```

Basically, when you select an item in a Spinner, this function is called. In the method, you can get the selected spinner item by:

```
String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
```

And then you can create a switch statement, so that depending on which spinner item was clicked, it converts the value into whatever it might be:

```
switch (selected) {
    case "FirstItem":
        // Convert value
        break;
    case "SecondItem":
        // Convert value
        break;
    ...
}
```

Also, remember to implement:

```
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
```

In your activity.